# How can I create dictionary within dictionary

Tags: python, excel, fwrite

I have the below code:

```
datedict = defaultdict(set)
with open('d:/info.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, 'excel')

    #passing the header
    read_header = False
    start_date=date(year=2009,month=1,day=1)
    #print((seen_date - start_date).days)
    tdic = {}
    for row in filereader: 
        if not read_header:
            read_header = True
            continue

# reading the rest rows
        name,id,firstseen = row[0],row[1],row[3]
        try:
            seen_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(firstseen, '%d/%m/%Y').date()               
            deltadays = (seen_date-start_date).days
            deltaweeks = deltadays/7 + 1
            key = name +'-'+id
            currentvalue = tdic.get(key, [])
            currentvalue.append(deltaweeks)
            tdic[key] = currentvalue

        except ValueError:
            print('Date value error')
            pass

tdic = dict((name, max(weeks) - min(weeks) + 1) for name, weeks in tdic.iteritems())

pprint.pprint(tdic)
```

in which I get the below result:

```
{'Mali-2': 20,
 'Gooki-3': 6,
 'Piata-4': 6,     
 'Goerge-5': 4,
 'Samoo-6': 1,
 'Marria-7': 2}
```

Now I would like to write and print the three items, name,id and weeks as separate columns  in an excel file. Anyone knows how it is possible?

Comment: Please fix your result, it's not valid python. @user2058811 Is that your desired result? Or is that what you have? It still isn't valid Python...

Comment: You said you want to print them to an excel file, my answer just prints them directly, is that fine?

Comment: that wasn't part of your original question, I suggest opening a new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for k, v in tdic.iteritems():
            name, id_ = k.split('-')
            weeks = v
            w.writerow([name, id_, weeks])


>>> with open('out.csv') as f:
        print f.read()


Piata,4,6    
Mali,2,20    
Goerge,5,4    
Gooki,3,6    
Samoo,6,1    
Marria,7,2
```

I however don't like the way you have done this, here are some suggestions for your code:

```
key = name +'-'+id
```

Instead of using string manipulation to create a key, use a `tuple`:

```
key = (name, id)
```

Change this line:

```
tdic = dict((name, max(weeks) - min(weeks) + 1) for name, weeks in tdic.iteritems())
```

to just say

```
tdic = dict((key, max(weeks) - min(weeks) + 1) for key, weeks in tdic.iteritems())
```

since now it is a key of `(name, id_)` we should reflect that (it's a minor thing but important)

Then the above code would simply be

```
>>> with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        for (name, id_), weeks in tdic.iteritems():
            w.writerow([name, id_, weeks])
```

Comment: @user2058811 oops I meant `tdic.iteritems()` not `d.iteritems()`. Also could you please post the output of `print tdic`

Comment: @user2058811 Change file extension to `.csv` which can be opened with excel

Comment: @user2058811 what do you mean? What is `.cvs`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28594/discussion-between-user2058811-and-jamylak)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a dict of dict like this:

```
a_dict = {key: { anotherKey: value}}
```

Or if the dict already exists:

```
a_dict[key] = {anotherkey: value}
print a_dict[key][anotherkey]
```